# Picture changing when it shouldn't

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a cinema app with flutter. The structure is as follows:

- in each city there are a bunch of cinemas
- in a cinema there are a bunch of showrooms(salle in french)
- in a showroom(salle in french) there are five display sessions or projections, these projections are of the same film.

because the projections are of the same movie (a showroom displays the same movie in different time(e.g projections) by design), when I click on any of the projections in a showroom I should have the same posture of the same film, not a different posture in each projection.

However I get a different film posture in each projection, and I don't know what is causing this.

I am using a rest api that I created with Spring, and I am certain that the problem is not from my back-end because I am using it in an angular web app and it's working perfectly.

This is a layout of my application
[image]

this is what happened when I click on two projection of the same showroom( notice that the posture changes when it shouldn't.

[image]

and here is the code of the showroom page (salles-page.dart)

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:movie_cinema_app/GlobalVariables.dart';

class SallesPage extends StatefulWidget {
dynamic cinema;
SallesPage(this.cinema);
@override
_SallesPageState createState() => _SallesPageState();
}

class _SallesPageState extends State<SallesPage> {
List<dynamic> listSalles;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Salles de ${widget.cinema['name']}'),
    ),
    body: Center(
        child: (listSalles == null)
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: (listSalles == null) ? 0 : listSalles.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                        color: Colors.white70,
                        child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    primary: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
                                child: Text(this.listSalles[index]['name'],
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                onPressed: () {
                                loadProjection(listSalles[index]);
                                },
                            ),
                            ),
                            if (this.listSalles[index]['projections'] != null)
                            Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                    Image.network(
                                    GlobalData.host +
                                        "/imageFilm/${this.listSalles[index]['currentProjection']['film']['id']}",
                                    //key: ValueKey(new Random().nextInt(100)),
                                    width: 150,
                                    ),
                                    IntrinsicWidth(
                                    child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                        children:<Widget> [
                                        ...(this.listSalles[index]['projections'] as List<dynamic>).map((projection){
                                            return ElevatedButton(
                                            child: Text("${projection['seance']['heureDebut']} (${projection['film']['duree']}H) - ${projection['prix']}DH",),
                                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                primary: (this.listSalles[index]['currentProjection']['id']==projection['id'])?Colors.lightGreen:Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                                            ),
                                            onPressed: (){
                                                onLoadTickets(projection, this.listSalles[index]);
                                            },
                                            );
                                        })
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                    ),
                                ],
                                ),
                            ),

                            if(this.listSalles[index]['currentProjection']!=null &&
                                this.listSalles[index]['currentProjection']['listTickets']!=null &&
                                this.listSalles[index]['currentProjection']['listTickets'].length>0)
                            Row(
                                children: <Widget> [
                                ...(this.listSalles[index]['currentProjection']['listTickets'] as List<dynamic>).map((ticket){
                                    if(ticket['reserve']==false)
                                    return Container(
                                        width: 50,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                        child: ElevatedButton(
                                        child: Text("${ticket['place']['numero']}"),
                                        onPressed: (){},
                                        ),
                                    );
                                    else return Container();
                                })
                                ],
                            )
                        ],
                        ));
                })),
    );
}

@override
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadSalles();
}

loadSalles() {
    String url = this.widget.cinema['_links']['salles']['href'];
    http.get(Uri.parse(url)).then((resp) {
    setState(() {
        this.listSalles = json.decode(resp.body)['_embedded']['salles'];
    });
    }).catchError((err) {
    print('error fetchhing salles of ${this.widget.cinema['name']}');
    });
}

void loadProjection(salle) {
    String url = salle['_links']['projections']['href']
        .toString()
        .replaceAll("{?projection}", "?projection=filmNeededInfoProjection");
    http.get(Uri.parse(url)).then((resp) {
    setState(() {
        salle['projections'] = json.decode(resp.body)['_embedded']['projections'];
        salle['currentProjection'] = salle['projections'][0];
        salle['currentProjection']['listTickets']=[];
    });
    }).catchError((err) {
    print(err);
    });
}

void onLoadTickets(projection, salle) {
    String url = projection['_links']['tickets']['href'].toString().replaceAll('{?projection}', '?projection=ticketProj');
    //String url2=GlobalData.host+"/projections/${projection['id']}tickets?projections=ticketsProj";
    http.get(Uri.parse(url)).then((resp){
    setState(() {
        projection['listTickets'] = json.decode(resp.body)['_embedded']['tickets'];
        salle['currentProjection']=projection;
    });
    }).catchError((err){
    print(err);
    });
}
}
```

here is the json output from the server:

Examle of json that `loadSalles()` function is working with:

```
{

"_embedded" : {

    "salles" : [ {

    "id" : 37,

    "name" : "Salle1",

    "nombrePlace" : 6,

    "_links" : {

        "self" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/salles/37"

        },

        "salle" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/salles/37"

        },

        "projections" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/salles/37/projections{?projection}",

        "templated" : true

        },

        "places" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/salles/37/places"

        },

        "cinema" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/salles/37/cinema"

        }

    }

    }
```

example json outputed by the server for the `loadProjections()` :

```
{

"_embedded" : {

    "projections" : [ {

    "id" : 1,

    "salle" : {

        "id" : 1,

        "name" : "Salle1",

        "nombrePlace" : 18

    },

    "tickets" : [ {

        "id" : 1,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 2,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 3,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 4,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 5,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 6,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 7,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 8,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 9,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 10,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 11,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 12,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 13,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 14,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 15,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 16,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 17,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    }, {

        "id" : 18,

        "nomClient" : null,

        "prix" : 30.0,

        "codePayement" : 0,

        "reserve" : false

    } ],

    "prix" : 30.0,

    "film" : {

        "id" : 1,

        "titre" : "12 Homme en colere",

        "decription" : null,

        "realisateur" : null,

        "dateSortie" : null,

        "duree" : 3.0,

        "photo" : "12Hommeencolere.jpg"

    },

    "seance" : {

        "heureDebut" : "12:00:00"

    },

    "dateProjection" : "2021-06-11T23:00:00.000+00:00",

    "_links" : {

        "self" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/projections/1"

        },

        "projection" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/projections/1{?projection}",

        "templated" : true

        },

        "seance" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/projections/1/seance"

        },

        "tickets" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/projections/1/tickets{?projection}",

        "templated" : true

        },

        "film" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/projections/1/film"

        },

        "salle" : {

        "href" : "http://192.168.8.106:8080/projections/1/salle"

        }

    }

    },
```

example json outputed by the server for the `onLoadTicket(projection,salle)` :

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "tickets": [
    {
        "id": 19,
        "nomClient": null,
        "codePayement": 0,
        "prix": 70,
        "place": {
        "numero": 1,
        "longitude": 0,
        "latidude": 0,
        "altitude": 0
        },
        "reserve": false,
        "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://192.168.8.106:8080/tickets/19"
        },
        "ticket": {
            "href": "http://192.168.8.106:8080/tickets/19{?projection}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "projection": {
            "href": "http://192.168.8.106:8080/tickets/19/projection{?projection}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "place": {
            "href": "http://192.168.8.106:8080/tickets/19/place"
        }
        }
    },
```

and here is my code, as it stands, on github:

[front end](https://github.com/JammingJack/Cinema-mobile-app-with-flutter)

[back end](https://github.com/JammingJack/cinema_backend) (although i recommend disregarding the last commit that adds spring security and working with this [commit](https://github.com/JammingJack/cinema_backend/commit/e39bc149ec12a8385e9068e2323cf029373bef4a) )

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be a formatting error, due to which the image is not loading. do try to update the question, It would be helpful to see the image as well :)

Comment: @RohanThacker Hello sir, I have updated my question with the images, thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: Thank you, Much easier to debug now

Comment: Could the problem be `salle['currentProjection']=projection;` in `onLoadTickets`? This causes the URL given to `Image.network` to change?

Comment: @RohanThacker unlikely kind sir, because all the projections of the showroom( salle) have the same film, that line is used to retrieve the list of tickets for that projection .

Comment: I see. I'm not sure what else could be causing the issue at the moment or how to debug this without spamming StackOverflow with comments

Comment: I see, well thank you for giving it a shot. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you can share the app code ( Github/Gitlab? ) and a copy of the json response from server. I'm sure we can figure it out. Let me know if you would want to do that

Comment: @RohanThacker I have updated the post with example of the json outputed by the server, and links to both the front end and back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem related to back-end and have nothing to do with Flutter.